# Jmeter Controllers for stateful testing

Tags: controller, jmeter

the requirement to test

1. Banker creates a account (insert)
2. After creating account add money to account (update)

Step 2 cannot happen without step 1 being complete. 
When I try to use Jmeter to test this scenario what type of controllers I should be using.

Suppose I create 10 accounts. 
There will be 10 HTTP requests.
Similarly there will be 10 HTTP request to update account

what i want to do is, as soon as the account is created I would like to update the account. For e.g if  an account is created say (account#1) I would like to send the update HTTP request immediately  while the creation od 2,3,4,5.. accounts are in progress

How do I know if the 1st HTTP request is completed and based on the response send the second one to update

Answer (score 0):

You can use `If controller` in JMeter to send the update account HTTP requests only if the `create account` request creates an account.

Add a `Beanshell Post Processor` in JMeter as a child element of Create Account HTTP request.

`prev.getResponseDataAsString()` will give you the HTTP response (the HTML). I assume there will be some confirmation message.

```
UpdateAccount = "FALSE";
if(prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("Account Created Successfully"))
     UpdateAccount = "TRUE";
 vars.put("UpdateAccountFlag", UpdateAccount);
```

- Now add a `if controller` to check the value of `UpdateAccountFlag`.

  ```
  Condition:   ${UpdateAccountFlag}
  Check Interpret condition as variable expression
  ```

This way - we can send the update account request only if we had received the account creation confirmation message.